# Problema ao calcular média

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um programa, no qual se dá a nota de duas provas, P1 e P2. Você soma e divide por 2 para pegar a média. Se ela for maior do que 6, o programa retorna a seguinte frase: **Aprovado**. Se a média for menor que 4, o programa retorna a seguinte frase: **Reprovado**. Agora, se a nota estiver entre 4 e 6, o programa pede a nota da prova de recuperação (VS), e se ela for maior do que 6, retorna: **Aprovado**, ou se a nota for menor que 6 ele retorna: **Reprovado**.

Queria pedir ajuda, em que parte errei no problema.

Obs.: Não posso usar Scanner. Tenho de manter desta maneira mesmo, só que não consigo fazer rodar o programa.

```
class Media {
    public static double Media( float P1, float P2) {
        double Media = (P1 + P2) / 2;
    } 

    public static double VS( float nota) {
        double VS = nota;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        if (Media >= 6) { 
            System.out.println("Aprovado.");
        } 
        else if (Media < 4) {
            System.out.println("Reprovado."); 
        } 
        else { 
            if( nota >= 6) {
                System.out.println("Aprovado."); 
            } 
            else { 
                System.out.println("Reprovado."); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Como são passadas as notas para seu programa?

Comment: voce tem dois problemas: 1) seu programa não roda; 2)vc não le os dados de entrada em momento nenhum, como voce pretende passar essas informações para o seu programa?

Comment: `Media` e `VS` deveriam retornar um valor `double`, mas em vez disso você criar uma nova variável que não faz nada dentro da função.

Comment: `if (Media >= 6) { ` média é uma classe, vc nao pode fazer essa comparação com classes, apenas com variáveis

Answer (score 1):

Seu código apresenta alguns problemas:

- `Media` já é o nome da classe, portanto ela não deve ser usada para designar o nome de um método pois dessa maneira ele se confunde com um possível construtor da mesma;
- Defina se você irá utilizar `float` ou `double` para trabalhar adequadamente com o método que retorna a média de notas;
- Seu método `VS` está inicializando uma variável local que não tem funcionalidade alguma;
- Seus métodos não estão retornando nenhum valor;
- Ao chamar o método que calcula a média dentro de `main`, você está esquecendo de passar os argumentos referentes às notas das provas P1 e P2;
- Você precisa obter as notas de todas as provas (P1, P2 e Recuperação) de alguma maneira, seja solicitando a entrada de dados por parte do usuário ou não.

Uma possível solução seria:

```
class Media {

    public static float media(float P1, float P2) {
        return (P1 + P2) / 2;
    } 

    public static void main(String [] args) { 

        float notaP1 = 10, notaP2 = 5, notaRecuperacao = 6;

        if ( media(notaP1, notaP2) >= 6) { 
            System.out.println("Aprovado.");
        } 
        else if (media(notaP1, notaP2) < 4) {
            System.out.println("Reprovado."); 
        } 
        else { 
            if( notaRecuperacao >= 6) {
                System.out.println("Aprovado."); 
            } 
            else { 
                System.out.println("Reprovado."); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `Media já é o nome da classe, portanto ela não pode ser usada para designar o nome de uma função;` Pode sim, faça o teste. PS: de preferência diga método ao invés de função, existe uma diferença de conceito

Comment: Ah sim, ao dizer que ela não pode me referi ao fato de gerar uma confusão com um possível construtor da classe. Obrigado pelo lembrete sobre métodos, é realmente conveniente quando se trata de OOP designá-los assim pelo fato de sempre pertencerem a um objeto (ou classe). (: